# Is it possible to create an object in the name of the parameter in C#?

Tags: c#

i have this situation to create an object in the name of the parameter passed.

```
public static void createobject()
    {
        createobjectInName("name");
        createobjectInName("id");
    }

    public static void createobjectInName(Object obj)
    {
        obj = new Object();
    }
```

here i want to call the object name and id.. but it will create object obj.
Any help... 
thanks

Comment: Objects do not have names although they can be "named" by variables and properties (which do have names). Generally it is inadvisable to desire to access a variable (or property) by a string name. To access an object by a given string value, a Dictionary is often suitable. Can you provide more context as to what the *end goal* is?

Comment: You might want to look into [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx). It is good for autogenereting code

Comment: @JensKloster It's also an advanced topic with a very specific set of useful situations .. which is likely out of place here.

Comment: @user2246674 I desagree - It is the only way (I know) to generate variable names that is as dynamic as OP suggest. It is offcource a **horrible idea** to even try it - but depinding on the context, it might be worth a try. Properly a less strick programming language is the right way to go here

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for is a `ref` or `out` param:

```
public static void createobject()
{
    createobjectInName(out name);
    createobjectInName(out id);
}

public static void createobjectInName(out Object obj)
{
    obj = new Object();
}
```

Note that `name` and `id` must be defined for this to work. You cannot create variables with an arbitrary name during runtime and it would be pointless anyway since no code could access it (if the accessing code also uses dynamic names you want a Dictionary instead that maps strings to objects).